# Delay in command metrics getting updated in Hystrix?

Tags: java, hystrix

I'm using Hystrix for its circuit breaker functionality, and I've noticed that the breaker isn't immediately tripped when the required criteria is met.

For example with the following configuration:

```
withCircuitBreakerRequestVolumeThreshold(2),
withCircuitBreakerErrorThresholdPercentage(50)
```

If I execute the following set of commands synchronously (assume C1-C3 have the same CommandKey) C3 behaves in a way I find to be unexpected:

```
// C1: Execute no-op command -- Error threshold 0%, Volume threshold 1
// C2: Execute exception throwing command -- Error threshold 50%, Volume threshold 2
// ---- Breaker should be tripped ----
// C3: Execute no-op command -- This command executes!  But the circuit should be tripped!
```

What I've found is if I check `HystrixCommandMetrics` before C3 the `HealthMetrics` show that no commands have been executed in the rolling window.

However, if I add a `Thread.Sleep(2_000)` before C3, then the metrics show as I'd expect AND C3 fails as I'd expect with a `FailureType.SHORTCIRCUIT`.

Are metrics in Hystrix not "live"?  That is, are they managed by a separate thread?  If this is the case, perhaps I shouldn't assume that the circuit breaker will trip immediately.

As a follow on, is there a way to force the metrics to be live?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that `HystricCommandMetrics#getHealthCounts` is only recalculated once per the period of time specified for a given command using `metricsHealthSnapshotIntervalInMilliseconds`.

By default this interval is 500ms.

As an additional note, calling `getHealthCounts` for a given command prior to `metricsHealthSnapshotIntervalInMilliseconds` ms after calling the command for the first time will result in `new HealthCounts(0,0,0)`.

That is, the health counts will reflect the values they were initialized with until the period has expired for the first time.